# PIG - Create a tuple line from flat file

Tags: tuples, apache-pig

I'm trying to create a tuple in Pig, but the format of file is not much friendly:

```
File Format:
Name: Zach
LastName: Red
Address: 34 Store Av 
Age: 34
Name: Brian
LastName: Curts
Address: 123 Street Av 
Age: 23
```

I need to create a tuple:

```
Name: Zach LastName: Red Address: 34 Store Av Age: 34
Name: Brian LastName: Curts Address: 123 Street Av Age: 23
```

Comment: Are you SURE that ALL your 'rows' have 4 elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own UDF in Java/Python/... to load this data. Check doc:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/udf.html#load-store-functions

Comment: probably one of the ugliest, most painful things one can find himself doing... but yea :)

Answer (score 0):

Crazy idea, but it might work; I ASSUME all your elements have 4 rows. Otherwise - it won't work.

1. Load the file using PigStorage
2. Use the RANK operator to generate a RANK field for each row. First row would get 1, 2nd row would get 2, etc.
3. For each row generate another number, between 1-4, based on its type: 1 for name, 2 for LastName, 3 for Address, 4 for Age. Let's call it 'RecordType'
4. add another field which would be FLOOR((RANK-1)/4). Name it 'PersonID'. For the 1st person it would be 0, for the 2nd one it would be 1, etc.
5. Now you can group by PersonID to get all records for the same person 'together'.
6. Now, for each person you would get the PersonID, and a bag containing all the records. We need to get them sorted. For that purpose you can use

   output = foreach Person {
       sorted = order PersonRows by RecordType;
       generate PersonID,sorted;
   }
7. Flatten the Bag into a Tuple using the BagToTuple function

and you're done.

Comment: Thank You Guys for reply it, but I created a Python script make it and i'm running with spark-submit.